# Convert a String to float in java

Tags: java, string, string-conversion, parsefloat

I'm trying to parse a String to a float with the `float.parsefloat()` method but it gives me an error concerning the format.

```
int v_CurrentPosX = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(v_posString)); //where v_posString is the float that I want to convert in this case 5,828
```

And the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "5,828"   at
>   sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
>     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)

Comment: hint: 5,828 could be a float depending on your ***LOCALE***

Comment: What is your `LOCALE`?

Comment: change your input string from ```5,828``` to ```5.828```

Comment: it the same problem if i let dot and what is a LOCALE ?

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale)  the Locale defines officially used format of numbers, dates, time, etc. I'd use the DataFormat class and with the correct Local it could infer that "," is as well a decimal separator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that colon (**,**) is not a default locale in the JVM...

you can use a NumberFormat for that, with the right locale

```
String x = "5,828";
NumberFormat myNumForm = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
double myParsedFrenchNumber = (double) myNumForm.parse(x);
System.out.println("D: " + myParsedFrenchNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the comma with a dot before parsing like so:

```
v_posString =  v_posString.replace(",",".");
int v_CurrentPosX = Math.round(Float.parseFloat(v_posString));
```

The problem is that your locale is set to use `.` for floats and not `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE).parse("5,828");
```

Answer (score 0):

Float.parseFloat() doesn't consider locale and always expects '.' to be your decimal point separator. You can use DecimalFormat instead.

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');

    String str = "5,200";

    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
    format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
    float f = format.parse(str).floatValue();
```